# Setting timer to an asynchronous request

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, wsdl

i have the functions that genereted by wsdl and one of them is an asynchronous one that has also an event.

```
ws.GetRequest("Login","Username","Password");
ws.GetRequestCompleted+=delegate(object sender,WS.GetRequestCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //somecode
}
```

i want to create a timer for the request above ,if after a while the GetRequestCompleted won't occur,  i will display an error message.
I do not have access to change to wsdl functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do two things:

- Start a timer when the request starts
- When the timer fires, if the callback hasn't been called, throw an exception

It looks like this is happening in a method and you're using anonymous methods as well for the delegate signatures, so I'd recommend using closures, like so:

```
// Let's say you want to wait for 5 seconds.
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

// Has the timer completed?  The callback on the web service?
bool wsCompleted = false, timerCompleted = false, exceptionThrown = false;

// Need to synchronize access to above, since it will come back on
// different threads.
object l = new object();

// Set up the callback on the timer.
t.Elapsed = delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    // Lock access.
    lock (l)
    {
        // Set the flag to true.
        timerCompleted = true;

        // If the web service has not completed and
        // the exception was not thrown, then
        // throw your exception here.
        if (!wsCompleted && !exceptionThrown) 
        {
            // The exception is being thrown.
            exceptionThrown = true;
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
};

// Set up the callback on the web service.
ws.GetRequestCompleted += 
    delegate(object sender,WS.GetRequestCompletedEventArgs e) {
        // Dispose of timer when done.
        using (t)
        // Lock.
        lock (l)
        {
            // The web service call has completed.
            wsCompleted = true;

            // If the timer completed and the exception was
            // not thrown, then do so here.
            if (timerCompleted && !exceptionThrown)
            {
                // The exception is being thrown.
                exceptionThrown = true;
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        // Handle callback.
    };

// Start the timer, make the web service call.
t.Start();
ws.GetRequest("Login","Username","Password");
```

Some things to note:

- You have to check in both the timer callback and the web service callback if the other condition has *not* been met and if the exception has *not* been thrown.  You don't want to throw the exception twice.
- You didn't indicate how you are getting the exception back to the user.  Right now, this exception will be thrown on a thread other than the calling thread.  It will result in a very unsightly exception for the user.
- The disposal of the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instance is handled in the callback for the web service.  This assumes that the callback for the webservice will *always* complete, success or not.

Comment: what i did is to stop the web service when the timer got to the end or stop the timer when the web service completed and i added a callback inside the getcomplete event.